# QT C++ create "global header" for a static library

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries

I created a static library whit this structure:

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

SOURCES += test.cpp 

HEADERS += test.h 

unix {
  target.path = /usr/lib
  INSTALLS += target
}
```

I know that i have also to include in the .pro file of the project those rows

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ -lTest
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs
```

and then the header.

```
#include "test.h"
```

My question is: if i have to add to the library more than one source file like:

```
SOURCES += test.cpp \
           control.cpp
HEADERS += test.h \
           control.h
```

how can create a global header file to import in my project (indeed to put in the `INCLUDEPATH` directory also the `control.h` header?

What i mean is: it's possible to include together to the generated lib(.a) only one header file that contains the others headers?

thanks in advance

Comment: How about add one .h file in your lib that only contains the `#include` for the other files ?

Comment: Right, but when i included that header, Creator Complains about the other headers inside that file

Comment: What does it say in its complaint ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create any custom header file in QtCreator (File -> New File -> C++ -> C++ Header File), then your .pro will contain it in HEADERS and you can put any #include you want in it.

However in my opinion it's a very bad practice to have all .h included in only one. Not only because of the compilation time when you'll have plenty of classes, but also because when classes have circular references, you'll get stucked (this is I think the main reason not to do what you're trying to do).

My 2 cents.